# Python-USDA client throwing package error. What is the right package name?

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to connect to the USDA API using python-usda, using the following process as mentioned in the PyPI docs.

Installing with `pip install python-usda` and then importing with `from usda.client import UsdaClient`.

This throws an error:

```
from usda.client import UsdaClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'usda.client'; 'usda' is not a package
```

What package should I be trying to import?

Comment: The code worked for me. Make sure you're using Python 3.4 or later.

Comment: That error message implies that you have a file in your local directory named `usda.py` (or perhaps `usda.pyc`).

Comment: According to [the docs](https://python-usda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) this should read `from usda import UsdaClient`

Comment: Thank you @John Gordon. I'm quite new to Python and had named my file 'usda.py'. Renaming the file worked. Would you be so kind as to deconstruct the error for me please?

Comment: Imports generally look in the current directory first, so it found your local file `usda.py`, which of course did not contain the `client` submodule.